# IPhone phonegap pdf issue

Tags: iphone, mobile-safari, cordova

I have a strange issue in phonegap framework. I want to display PDF file in my application, when I am trying to add PDF file with **iFrame** tag it doesn't show a PDF with horizontal scroll and with a big zoom size. so getting out of screen.

I tried by another way using **embed** tag, its also having same problem with addition to that its showing PDF for only first time in the application.

If anybody know how to display a PDF in phonegap with specified zoom level or with scroll bar. Above code is working fine in iPhone mobile safari, but not in phonegap. Any Idea?

Thanks.

Comment: That is very strange! I would not think that PhoneGap is doing anything differently from iPhone mobile safari. Can you post some of the code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To display pdf in phonegap,
have lots of trouble,
but best solution so far,is to used ChildBrowser Plugin for phonegap here is the link-
https://github.com/purplecabbage/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iPhone/ChildBrowser
this will help you to call child native uiwebview in your application(only for iphone),
so you can easily enjoy pinch zoom feature

Answer (score 1):

Using Phonegap you'll have only one UIWebView so probably the best idea is to open the pdf as a new object link using rel=external

Other suggestion is look at the view-port size, maybe you'll have to increase it's size to allow the pinch and zoom.